# SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol replacing with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I'm trying to use pandas to download historical stock data for all Stockholm Large Cap stocks. It works fine but for some stocks it doesn't.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import datetime
import csv

with open('stockholm_largecap.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    stockholmLargeCap = list(reader)

start = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.today();

stockData = {}

for symbol in stockholmLargeCap:
    f = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', start, end)
    print f
```

The stockholm_largecap.csv contains all stocks in alphabetical order but once I get to certain stocks I get (for example BETS-B.ST): SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'BETS-B.ST', replacing with NaN. and the script terminates. Is there some way to continue the program, ignoring the error and what could be the cause of some stocks not working?

```
raise RemoteDataError(msg.format(self.__class__.__name__))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: No data fetched using 'YahooDailyReader'
```

Comment: copy the error you get, so we can see what ValueError is raised

Comment: Sorry, added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `try` and `except`

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

for symbol in ['SPY', 'holla']:
    try:
        f = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', "2001-01-01", "2010-01-01")
        print f.head(5)
    except:
        print ('did not find: '+symbol)

               Open     High      Low    Close    Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                               
2001-01-02 132.0000 132.1562 127.5625 128.8125   8737500    95.2724
2001-01-03 128.3125 136.0000 127.6562 135.0000  19431600    99.8488
2001-01-04 134.9375 135.4687 133.0000 133.5468   9219000    98.7740
2001-01-05 133.4687 133.6250 129.1875 129.1875  12911400    95.5497
2001-01-08 129.8750 130.1875 127.6875 130.1875   6625300    96.2893
did not find: holla
```

Comment: I added the RemoteDataError (as you presumed correctly) to the question. Though now I get "except RemoteDataError:
NameError: name 'RemoteDataError' is not defined".

Comment: try the new version, if it doesnt work remove the RemoteDataError

Comment: It didn't work with RemoteDataError and when I removed it, it didn't find any ticker, not even the ones that work before.

Comment: should work, I tried with fake tickers and getting the correct output

Comment: Seems to have been something cached, worked when I restarted. Though I wonder why many of the stocks won't work.

Comment: the problem is yahoo. if you look at [BETS-B.ST](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BETS-B.ST/history?p=BETS-B.ST) you can't event grab the csv from the website you will get [this error](http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BETS-B.ST&a=8&b=14&c=2016&d=9&e=14&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv)

Comment: Ah, shame. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: you can accept the answer if you want to close this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was trying to get stocks from a list , I used exception handling block which continued the execution of the code despite of the symbol warning viz.[ SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'AXZZW', replacing with NaN.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)]

```
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError
from pandas_datareader.data import Options
try:
    df1 = web.DataReader(rows[i],'yahoo',"2001-01-01","2010-01-01")
    print("Downloading",i,"/",len(rows),"............")
    print(df1)
except KeyError:
    print("Data not found at Ticker %s"%i)
    continue
except RemoteDataError:
    print("Data not found at Ticker %s"%i)
    continue
print("Success!")
```

Hope this works for you too!